# Jquery scroll - wait - scroll

Tags: jquery, animation, mousemove

I'm doing a "trip" actions on my website. If person, when he comes to website didn't do anything for 3 seconds, then the trip begins:

```
var stop_timeout = false; // function for page trip
        $(function() {
            $("#begin").mousemove(function() {
                clearTimeout(stop_timeout);
                stop_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    //alert("The mouse has stopped.");
                    scroll("#about");
                }, 3000);            
            });
        });
```

and what I want to do, that the person should be dropped to the next section when he didn'nt move the mouse on "about" section. I imagine something like this:

> wait - scroll to #about - wait - scroll to #services - wait - scroll
>   to #contact

how should i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to solve it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LePhil/zgwn9/

travel() calls itself recursively, I'm sure you can solve it in different ways but this way was the most obvious for me.
For the jQuery selectors you could also find a solution with .next(), I'd say, but to make it clearer I used an array. Hope this helps!

```
var timer,
elementsToScrollTo = ["#second", "#third", "#fourth"],
breaker = false;

$(document).on("click, mousemove", function() {
    stop();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    travel(0);
});


function travel(i) {
    timer = setTimeout( function () {
        if ( breaker ) { return; }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( elementsToScrollTo[i] ).offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
            if ( i+1 >= elementsToScrollTo.length ) {
                stop();
            } else {
                travel(i+1);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}
function stop() {
    console.log("stopping");
    breaker = true;
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```